# foreach в ассоциативном массиве powershell

Tags: powershell

Не могу прочитать массив в нужном мне порядке как я его задаю в ручную в powershell скрипте.
Не сколько вариантов которые я пробовал:

```
1 способ 
$hash = @{"name"="1";"name3"="2";"name0"="3"}

foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
$h.Name  
}

1 способ результат 
name
name0
name3
```

Как видно массив задан в одном виде, foreach проходится как ему легче видимо.

```
2 способ найден на просторах интернета с использованием [ordered]
$hash = [ordered]@{"name"="1";"name3"="2";"name0"="3"}

foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
$h.Name  
}

2 способ результат

Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Тут я немного начал нервничать так либо синтаксис не соблюдаю, либо powershell все больше меня не любит.

```
3 Способ Решил применить цикл for (Думал у меня тут получится обмануть и все пройдет)
$hash = @{"name"="1";"name3"="2";"name0"="3"}

for ($i=0;$i -lt $hash.count;$i++)
{
$i
$hash[$i]
}

3 Способ результат 
0
1
2
```

Как видно в последнем способе он правильно посчитал кол-во элементов, но по индексу вывести не хочет.

И повторю проблему.

Мне нужно чтобы цикл выполнялся в нужном для меня порядке, а именно так как я его прописал в $hash.
То есть:
name
name3
name0

Comment: Для ассоциативных массивов сохранение порядка обычно не гарантируется.

Answer (score 1):

`$hash = [ordered]@{"name"="1";"name3"="2";"name0"="3"}` [работает в PowerShell 4.0](http://savepic.net/8024836.htm) по крайней мере.

Если вы не можете обновиться до PowerShell 4.0, то попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$dict = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]'
$dict.add('name',  1);
$dict.add('name3', 2);
$dict.add('name0', 3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да так и есть. Спасибо!